# hoffman-and-kunze [chapter 8.2][question 4]

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory, inner-products

The question:
Let Y be a finite-dimensional inner product space and T a linear operator on Y. Show that the range of T* is the orthogonal complement of the null space of T

Think i got one way:

took v$\in$Im(T*)
and u$\in$Ker(T)

will show $(u|v)=0$

v$\in$Im(T*) => there is v'$\in$Y for it T*(v') = v

(u|T*(v')) = (T(u)|v') = (0|v') = 0

and this is true for any u$\in$Ker(T)
=> v is in the complement of Ker(T)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The range of $T^*$ is the orthogonal complement of $Ker(T)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/318136/the-range-of-t-is-the-orthogonal-complement-of-kert)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you know about $\dim(\ker(T))$ and $\dim({\rm Im}(T)$?  What do you know about $\dim({\rm Im}(T))$ and $\dim({\rm Im}(T^*))$?

Comment: dim(Im(T)) + dim(ker(T)) = dimY,dim(KerT) + dim(complement of kerT) = dimY => dim(ImT) = dim(complement of KerT)

Comment: Want to show that dim(Im(T*)) = dim(Im(T)) Cannot figure out the way..

Comment: ok i think i got it, since we know the matrix of T* is the conjugate transpose of the matrix of T we know r(T*) = r(T) => dim(Im(T)) = dim(Im(T*)). Thank you.