# If T is a reflection then $Ker (T-Id) = Im (T-Id)^{\perp}$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, orthogonality, reflection

Let V be a finite dimensional space with inner product . If  T is an orthogonal transformation and a reflection then  $ Ker (T-Id) = Im (T-Id)^{\perp}$, where $Id$ denotes the identity matrix

I know that $det(T) = -1 $  because T is a reflection ,that $T^2 = Id$ and that at least one eigenvalue of T is $-1$ , but I am not finding a way to proceed.

Any hints ?

Comment: Yes it is the orthogonal complement. There is an inner product on V, I forgot to mention sorry

Comment: I have already edited it.

Comment: You can try to apply the result in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/318136/the-range-of-t-is-the-orthogonal-complement-of-kert).