# Suppose that $f$ is a linear transformation on a finite dimensional inner product space $V$...

Tags: linear-algebra

Show that the range of $f^*$ is orthogonal complement of the nullspace of $f$. Deduce that the rank of $f$ is equal to the rank of $f^*$, Deduce that the row rank of a square matrix is equal to its column rank.

There are so many technical questions in my workbook I am getting confused here.

Comment: Take them one at a time then. Lumping them all together makes it seem so much harder. For example, you can find an answer to your first question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/318136/the-range-of-t-is-the-orthogonal-complement-of-kert), though I'd recommend reviewing the definition of adjoint, orthogonal complement, and nullspace, as the result really just falls out from using these three definitions.

Comment: I edited your question, adding "\$" signs to make the $\LaTeX$ work.  Cheers!