# Inhomogenous linear system with singular Hermitian matrix: question on orthogonality of solutions.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, systems-of-equations

Given a Hermitian matrix $A$ with a kernel (or nullspace) spanned by vector $u$, i.e. $Au=0$.  Then for inhomogeneous equation $Ax=b$, must $(x,u) = 0$?

In other words, for singular Hermitian $A$, does a particular solution to the inhomogeneous problem have to be orthogonal to the homogeneous solution space?

Comment: no. If $Ax = b$ while $Aw = 0,$ we certainly have $A(x+ tw) = b$ where $t$ is a number, either real or complex.  Maybe you should make up a brief example for us

Comment: For Hermitian matrices [$\textrm{Ker}(A)=\textrm{Ran}(A)^\perp$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/318136/152568). Did you mean $(b,u) = 0$?

Comment: @Conifold Thanks. No - I'd assumed $(b,u)=0$ by the Fredholm Alternative (since $A$ Hermitian).

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $x$ is a solution to the inhomogenous. Then $x + cu$ is also a solution for any scalar $c$.

Now assume all particular solutions are orthogonal to u. Then
$$\langle u, x \rangle = 0$$ 
and 
$$\langle u, x + cu \rangle = \langle u, x \rangle + c||u||^2 = 0.$$
This implies
$$c||u||^2 = 0.$$
But $u$ is a nonzero vector, and so it has a positive norm, and we have reached a contradiction. Therefore the assumption was false; not all particular solutions to the inhomogenous are orthogonal to $u$.

Comment: Thanks for your very clear and succinct answer, Ameer (it's also solved another problem I had).