# Why if T is normal linear map, then image of T if the same as image of T*?

Tags: linear-algebra, adjoint-operators, normal-operator

If $T$ is a normal linear map from vector space $V$ to itself, then image of $T$ is the same as image of $T^*$.

Can anyone help me to prove this?

Comment: From $\|Tx\|^2=(Tx,Tx)=(T^*Tx,x)=(TT^*x,x)=(T^*x,T^*x)=\|T^*x\|^2$ you get that $\operatorname{Ker}(T)=\operatorname{Ker}(T^*)$. Then [prove that the image is the orthogonal complement of the kernel](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/318136/917479).

Comment: @plop In general, the orthogonal complement of the kernel is the closure of the image, so this argument only shows that the closures of the images coincide.

Comment: @QuantumSpace This argument shows that they are equal in the finite-dimensional case. If you want it for a general Hilbert, quotient out the kernel and consider the extension to the closure of their ranges of operator $U=A^*A^{-1}$. You get that $A^*U=A$ and $A^*=AU$, which implies that their ranges are themselves equal.

Comment: Thank you very much @plop

Comment: Am I supposed to write an answer myself now? @plop