# If $T$ is a self-adjoint operator, then $\text{ker}T\perp\overline{\text{Im}T}$.

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification

Currently I'm self studying functional analysis, namely self-adjoint operators. In the text, the author gives the following exercise:

> **Exercise A**: If $T$ is a self-adjoint operator, then $\text{ker}T\perp\overline{\text{Im}T}$.

I think I've tackled this on my own, but I can't find this problem anywhere to verify my solution below. Hence, I'm asking here: is this solution correct?

**Solution**: Let $x\in\text{ker}T$ and $y\in\overline{\text{Im}T}$. By definition it follows that $Tx=0$ and $\exists\left(Tx_n\right)\in\text{Im}T$ for which $Tx_n\to y$. Therefore by the continuity of the inner product and self-ajointness of $T$,
$$
\langle x,y \rangle=
\lim\langle x,Tx_n \rangle=
\lim\langle Tx,x_n \rangle=
\lim\langle 0,x_n \rangle=
\lim0\cdot\langle 0,x_n \rangle=
0.
$$
This concludes the proof.

---

**EDIT**:

I actually misread the exercise. The exercise is actually the following:

> **Exercise B**: If $T$ is a self-adjoint operator, then $\text{ker}T\perp\text{Im}T$.

But this is simpler. Take $x\in\text{ker}T$ and $Ty\in\text{Im}T$. Then by the self-ajointness of $T$,
$$
\langle x,Ty \rangle=
\langle Tx,y \rangle=
\langle 0,y \rangle=
0\cdot\langle 0,y \rangle=
0.
$$
This concludes the proof.

Comment: It looks ok. However to be more precise, for $T:X\rightarrow X$ a self-adjoint linear operator, you could show that $Ker(T)=(Im(T))^{\perp}$ (equality actually holds). The direction $\subseteq$ is shown easily using what you have done. The direction $\supseteq$ is done with the help of the claim: If $z\in Im(T)^{\perp}$, and for all $w\in X$ such that $\langle T(z),w\rangle=0$, then $T(z)=0$.

Comment: @Representation: Interesting, thanks for the comment. However, what about the misread I had, i.e. **Exercise A**? Is that statement, and proof, correct too?

Comment: @D.Math everything ist correct

Comment: @daw: Great, thanks for the conformation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The range of $T^*$ is the orthogonal complement of $\ker(T)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/318136/the-range-of-t-is-the-orthogonal-complement-of-kert)