# equivalence of two conditions on two matrices

Tags: matrices, orthogonality

I would like to ask for your view on two different conditions for two matrices.

I have the two matrices mentioned above, say $\Lambda_1$ and $\Lambda_2$. Their dimensions are, for both matrices, $N\times P$, and $N>P$.
In some papers I am reading, I found that the following condition is needed

$\Lambda_2 \neq \Lambda_1 G$

for *all* matrices $G$, with $G$ of dimensions $P\times P$. Nothing else is said on $G$.

Working on a related problem, I need the condition

$\Lambda_2=\Lambda_1C + \tilde{\Lambda}_1$

where $C$ is some matrix of dimensions $P\times P$. I do not have any specific conditions on $C$ (e.g. it could have full rank or not, it could be nonzero or all zeros, etc...). On the other hand, $\tilde{\Lambda}_1$ is an $N\times P$ matrix which belongs in the orthogonal space of $\Lambda_1$ - I mean that

$\Lambda_1^{\prime}\tilde{\Lambda}_1=0$

My question is: how different are the two conditions mentioned above? Are they entirely equivalent, do they imply each other, does one imply the other at all...? Any comment would be welcome.

Comment: no no, by $\Lambda^{\prime}$ I meant the transpose, and $\Lambda$ is not even square, it is genuinely rectangular

Comment: I see, it is a dash not minus sign...

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{LT}{\Lambda_2}$ $\newcommand{LO}{\Lambda_1}$We first reduce this to a one-vector problem. Then, we will use one-dimensional theory to investigate the problems.

Let , for a matrix $M$, $M_i$ denote the columns of $M$ where $i$ runs from $1$ to the number of columns of $M$.

Now, what is $\Lambda_1 G$? Recall that $\Lambda_1 G$ can be computed as follows : we compute $\Lambda_1 G_i$ (as the product of a matrix and a vector) for $i=1$ to the number of columns of $G$, and then we put these columns together as a matrix so that $(\Lambda_1 G)_i = \Lambda_1G_i$.

With this, we make the following claim :

> There exists a matrix $G$ such that $\Lambda_1 G = \Lambda_2$, if and only if there exist $p$ column-vectors $G_1,...,G_p$ each of dimension $p \times 1$ such that $\Lambda_1G_i = (\Lambda_2)_i$ for all $i=1,2,...,p$. In other words, there is a $G$ such that $\Lambda_1 G = \Lambda_2$ if and only if each of the columns of $\Lambda_2$ lies in the image of $\Lambda_1$ treated as a transformation from $\mathbb R^p \to \mathbb R^n$.

The proof is clear : If $\Lambda_1 G = \Lambda_2$ then we can take the columns of such a $G$. On the other hand, if such vectors existed, we can create a matrix whose columns equal these vectors in the correct order, and such a matrix will satisfy the multiplication condition.

With this, we can now investigate the problem.

---

We will use an important fact : If $A : \mathbb R^l \to \mathbb R^m$ is a linear transformation, then $\mbox{Im}(A') = [\ker(A)]^\perp$. An answer to this can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/318136/the-range-of-t-is-the-orthogonal-complement-of-kert).

Let's use this to prove :

> Suppose that $\LT = \LO C + \widetilde{\LO}$ for a matrix $\widetilde{\LO} \neq 0$ that satisfies $\LO'\widetilde{\LO} = 0$. Then, for no matrix $G$ can it be true that $\LT = \LO G$.

Proof : Since $\widetilde{\LO} \neq 0$, there is a non-zero column of $\widetilde{\LO}$, say $(\widetilde{\LO})_i \neq 0$. Now, suppose that $\LT = \LO G$ for some matrix $G$. Taking the $i$th column on both sides and performing some rearrangement with the help of our result gives :
$$
(\LT)_i = (\LO G)_i \implies (\LO C + \widetilde{\LO})_i = (\LO G)_i \implies (\LO C)_i + (\widetilde{\LO})_i = (\LO G)_i \\ \implies \LO (G-C)_i = (\widetilde{\LO})_i
$$

Now, in the statement $\mbox{Im}(A') = [\ker(A)]^\perp$, replace $A$ by $A'$, then you get $\mbox{Im}(A) = [\ker(A')]^\perp$. Recognize that $\LO (G-C)_i \in \mbox{Im}(\LO) = [\ker(\LO')]^\perp$ while $(\widetilde{\LO})_i \in \ker(\LO')$. Therefore, the same vector belongs in both $\ker(\LO')$ and its orthogonal complement, but that implies that this vector must equal zero. That's a contradiction, since we chose $i$  such that $(\widetilde{\LO})_i \neq 0$.

Therefore, no such matrix $G$ can exist. $\blacksquare$

So we know for sure that the second condition being true implies that the first condition is true.

---

Let us now investigate if the opposite direction is true. For this, we will use the fact that for any finite dimensional space $V$ and subspace $W$ of $V$, we have the orthogonal decomposition $V = W \oplus W^\perp$.

In our case, take $W$ to be the subspace $\mbox{Im}(\LO)$, and in that case, $W^{\perp} = \ker(\LO')$. Thus, for any vector $v \in \mathbb R^n$, we can find vectors $v \in \mathbb R^p,w \in \mathbb R^n$ such that $v = \LO v + w$ where $\LO' w = 0$.

Suppose now, that $\LT$ is a given matrix. Using the above with the columns of $\LT$, we know that there exist $v_i \in \mathbb R^p,w_i \in \mathbb R^n$ such that $(\LT)_i = \LO v_i + w_i$ where $\LO' w_i =0$. Putting these together as columns of a matrix equality gives us :
$$
\LT = \LO V + W
$$

for some $p \times p$ matrix $V$ and $n \times p$ matrix $W$ such that $\LO'W = 0_{p \times p}$. In short, what we have proven is that for every $\LO,\LT$, such a decomposition as provided in the second condition, is possible.

Which means the following :

> Suppose that the second condition is false. Then, the first condition is false.

Proof : Suppose that the second condition is false. Then, use the above decomposition to write $\LT = \LO V + W$. Since the second condition is false, it MUST happen that $W = 0$. But then , $\LT = \LO V$ which means the first condition is false. $\blacksquare$

---

To summarize, we have proven the following.

> Theorem : For $n \times p$ matrices $\LO,\LT$, the following are equivalent :
>
> - For all $p \times p$ matrices $G$ , we have $\LT \neq \LO G$.
> - There exists a  $p \times p$ matrix $V$ and a *non-zero* $n \times p$ matrix $W$ such that $\LT = \LO V + W$ , with $\LO'W = 0_{p \times p}$.

Comment: thank you ever so much - very very thorough and, if I may, elegant answer which really helps me. really appreciated

Comment: @LorenzoTrapani Thank you! To be honest, being thorough helps me as an answer writer, I don't like missing details however small (although sometimes I use spoilers). Good to have been of help.